# Firefox: non-Vimperator way to do mouseless browsing?

Tags: firefox, keyboard-navigation

Is it possible to do efficient browsing with Firefox using
only the keyboard (like in Opera)?

By efficient I mean something faster than using TAB - this
takes far too long. The arrow keys should be for navigation
(in Opera it is Shift + arrow key). It can done with the
[Vimperator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vimperator) add-on or its successor [Pentadactyl](http://5digits.org/pentadactyl/),
but isn't there a simpler way?

---

The closest to Opera's way is to enable [caret
navigation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_navigation) (<kbd>F7</kbd> toggles this mode). It doesn't
jump between links so it is a little bit slower, but the
normal navigation (arrow keys, <kbd>page up</kbd>, <kbd>page
down</kbd>, etc.) works and the focus/caret/cursor follows
(in contrast to a text editor for page up/down). And text
can be selected and copied like in a text editor.

The biggest drawback is that in practice it is necessary to
switch in and out of caret mode. And there is no indication
of which mode is currently active.

---

A workaround (proposed by several, but is not
really what I am looking for) can be used if three settings are
changed (to make it practical). After these changes the
first few letters of a link text can be typed and that link
will selected so pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> will open it.

Using the workaround, the screen will jump around if it is a
long page as it does not restrict itself to the current
visible page, but it is usable.

Changes (see below for other versions of Firefox):

1. Hamburger menu (upper right) → *Preferences*
   → *General*. Under headline *Browsing* (scroll down) → *Search for text when I start typing*

   Turn this option on.
2. Set option to only go to links; in the address
   bar enter

   > about:config

   followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Then: press <kbd>Accept the Risk and Continue!</kbd>, find the line *accessibility.typeaheadfind.linksonly*, select the "toggle" icon (e.g. by <kbd>TAB</kbd>ing to it) and change the value to True by hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
3. Turn off case-sensitivity. Set
   *accessibility.typeaheadfind.casesensitive* to 0 (same
   procedure as for *accessibility.typeaheadfind.linksonly*, see
   above. When Enter is pressed a dialog box will appear with
   the current value. Type 0 and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>).

To use it: type some part of the link. If there are several
possibilities use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> (or <kbd>F3</kbd>)
to jump between them. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> to
open in a new tab.

#### For older versions of Firefox

It is the same as the above, except:

Option *Search for text when I start typing*:

```
menu Tools/Options/Advanced/tab General/Accessibility/Search for text when I start typing
```

Opening the *about:config* page, the button is <kbd>I'll be careful, I promise</kbd>.

Platform: Firefox 3.0.6, Windows XP 64 bit SP2.

Answer (score 19):

The web browser Firefox has two search keys: <kbd>/</kbd> searches any text; <kbd>'</kbd> searches for just links. Both continue the search with <kbd>F3</kbd>.

Comment: I'd forgotten about ' for links only. Thanks! +1

Comment: I only knew about Ctrl+F

Comment: I know about `/` for searching but I always enable *search when start typing*. Anyway the `'` is great

Comment: Information: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/search-contents-current-page-text-or-links

Answer (score 9):

Two suggestions:

1. Hitting the <kbd>F7</kbd> key toggles whether the arrow keys scroll the page or move the cursor. It's handy for selecting text, but it can also be useful for moving the cursor over top of a link.
2. Use the [MouselessBrowing](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/mouseless-browsing) extension. I haven't used it in quite some time, but it used to work very, very well.

Comment: Yes, F7, to toggle caret navigation, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_navigation, is closest to the way Opera operates. It is still not same as real physical navigation (between links) like Opera, but it is close enough to be useful, especially when combined with the type-and-jump-to-link described elsewhere here. On the other hand when the caret navigation mode is enabled it is possible to select and copy text using only the keyboard.

Comment: I second the MouselessBrowsing extension. http://www.mouseless.de/

Comment: As of now, it's https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/mouseless-plugin/

Answer (score 4):

Tick on *"Search for text when I start typing"* (menu *Tools* → *Options* → under headline *Browsing* (scroll down)), and then you can type the text of links and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, which massively increases speed of navigation.

(For older versions of Firefox, it is in *Options* → *Advanced* → *General*.)

Comment: Wow, didn't know of this option. Really cool...

Answer (score 3):

I've tried all the different methods and addons for keyboard navigation in Firefox, and the two I like the most are:

1. Press the <kbd>'</kbd> key, type the first few letters of a link and then immediately hit enter.
2. The Spatial Navigation script that can be found over at userscripts.org. Just like in Opera, you navigate between links with <kbd>Shift</kbd> and the arrow keys. It doesn't come close to the native spatial navigation in Opera, but it works about as well as the Crossfire addon for [Chrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome).

Comment: This seems to be a comment on previous answers.

Answer (score 2):

If I know the text of the link I want to go to, / (quick-find) works pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

I used [Numberfox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6420) for a while. It attaches a number to each link on a page so you can use (as Phoshi said) *Find As You Type* to find the link number. It was a bit cumbersome for me, but it might be what you're looking for. Unfortunately, it is only for Firefox 2, but if you disable addon update checking, it might work!

Answer (score 1):

[Hit-a-hint](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1341) is an addon that makes a user-defined key a special key which activates alphabetical hints for all the links on a page for easy following. [LoL](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/8781) is a fork of HaH that works with Firefox 3.5 and is more actively maintained.

This functionality is quite the same that is implemented also in [Vimperator](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4891)'s hint mode.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [gleeBox](http://thegleebox.com/) and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Hint-a-hint doesn't seem to support more recent browsers and the LoL link is broken and no extension named "LoL" seems to exist in the [mozilla addons repository](https://addons.mozilla.org/).

[Vimium](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/vimium) instead seems to be maintained and so far works here.

Answer (score 0):

## [VimFx](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/vimfx/)

> Even before Vimium there was Vimperator for Firefox. In my opinion,
> Vimperator has too many features and aggressively changes the default
> Firefox appearance and behavior. Vimium is exactly what I need in
> terms of added functionality, but for Chrome. That’s why I decided to
> develop a similar extension for Firefox.
>
> **VimFx will be nice to your browser and to your habits. Promise.**
>
> *– Anton Khodakivskiy, VimFx’s original author.*

Answer (score 0):

[saka-key](https://key.saka.io/) is very promising, building on the ideas from Vimium and  cVim, and is supporting both Firefox Quantum and Google Chrome. See the [clicking_and_link_hints](https://key.saka.io/tutorial/clicking_and_link_hints) documentation.

There are currently doubts about [its maintenance](https://github.com/lusakasa/saka/issues/12), but I hope the author will find support to help finalize and maintain this great work.